# Can I remove the beeper from my older Bosch fridge?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

The warning beeper keeps going off on my old Bosch fridge-freezer, but temperature's OK. This sound is really irritating but I don't want to pay the UK £117 callout and possibly the cost of a new circuit board for what is a 20 year-old machine, when the machine is keeping temperature OK.

I have the idea of cutting off the loudspeaker but does anyone know whether this can be accessed easily behind the top panel?

The Bosch ENR is KGU32163GB.

[image]

Comment: Does the door closure switch work and turn the light off? Could just be a faulty switch making the fridge think the door is open?

Answer (score 17):

I've replaced or disabled such piezo devices on several appliances (I don't even like that noise when it's working properly). It's usually not difficult to get access to the control board. There you can desolder or cut a leg of the buzzer. There's some risk that this will cause a fault, though. Do any modifications such that they're reversible if necessary.

Note that if your buzzer is sounding falsely there's probably more going on than you imply by your question. Obviously the temperature control circuitry is having a problem, and you risk losing or freezing food if you continue use of the refrigerator without addressing the core issue.

Note also that even a seemingly modern 20 year old refrigerator likely [uses much more energy](https://www.cleanenergyresourceteams.org/your-old-refrigerator-energy-hog) than a new one would. That may make replacement more appealing.

Comment: +1 to “figure out if there’s something really wrong”… fridge/ freezer temperature monitors can be really cheap insurance.

Comment: Another solition is to cover the front of the beeper with tape / cotton wool to mute the sound.

Comment: Then you'd have a _muffled_ pointless beep. :P

Comment: Last paragraph is highly sus. Even if it were true, a 20 year old fridge will last 20+ more, while a new one is likely to get bricked the next time there's an OTA firmware upgrade pushed, or just break physically from low-quality components since they assume you'll want the latest model with a new bigger touchscreen by the time it breaks anyway. These days I would always recommend repairing older appliances vs buying newer ones; the latter have gotten so out-of-control bad.

Comment: The the point of figuring out what's wrong, a 3rd party thermometer is inexpensive and will tell you if the built-in one is accurate.

Comment: With poor temperature control there is also a risk of getting sick!

Comment: To prevent the spread of misinformation, I concur with @R.GitHub as I have repaired appliances for 40 years.  Every model of frig is different, as is every family's use, every maintenance schedule, every environment's weather/climate, etc., etc.  It's easy to ASSUME that the newer designs are more efficient, but there are 3 problems with this: I know of no broad studies done of various models, over many, many years.  Only the mfrs. test/label their product's efficiency. A frig can be made more efficient by lightening the rotating parts--this means they will fail sooner, which wastes energy!

Comment: I agree that appliances are less reliable these days and that replacing solely for energy savings may not be wise. That's not the situation here, though. We have a failing control board and the potential for a lot of wasted food and even illness. Regarding the science, I choose to have some degree of trust in the Energy Star program.

Comment: Many thanks for these responses. Am weighing up options.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.